# How to update a boolean attribute in Rails using a patch request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, tdd, minitest

I have a boolean attribute that I'm trying to test using Minitest in Rails. Here's the test in question:

```
test "admins can change a user's board member status" do
    patch user_path(@member, as: @admin), params: { user: { board_member: true } }
    assert_redirected_to(user_path(@member))
    assert_equal "Profile was successfully updated.", flash[:notice]
    assert_equal true, @member.board_member
end
```

I don't understand why that's not working. I'm able to set the `board_member` attribute to `true` in my fixtures, db seeds, manually in the browser, and also in a system test with Capybara.

I tried setting passing the user params to the patch request with `to_json` but that did not work either. I keep getting the same error as if the boolean attribute was not toggled to true:

```
 test_admins_can_change_a_user's_board_member_status#UsersControllerTest (1.28s)
   Expected: true
   Actual: false
```

Here's how I'm whitelisting my params in the user's controller:

```
def user_params
   # List of common params
   list_params_allowed = [:email, :profile_photo, :first_name, :last_name, :title, :organization, :street, :city, :state, :zip_code, :phone]
   # Add the params only for admin
   list_params_allowed += [:role, :board_member] if current_user.admin?

   params.require(:user).permit(list_params_allowed)
end
```

Again, this works as expected in the browser, but I want to test the params to ensure there is no security hole if you try to submit the "board_member" attribute through a url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reload @member in order for it to reflect the changes made by your app to the database.

```
test "admins can change a user's board member status" do
  assert_changes -> { @member.board_member }, from: false, to: true do
    patch user_path(@member, as: @admin), params: { user: { board_member: true } }
    @member.reload # get changes performed by app to db
  end
  # consider extracting this into separate examples
  assert_redirected_to(user_path(@member))
  assert_equal "Profile was successfully updated.", flash[:notice]
end
```

Comment: Although I wouldn't really recommend building it this way. A better solution would be to have a separate table to keep track of the users roles. That lets you add additional features like keeping track of when a user was granted a role, who granted the role and you can also "revoke" roles with a soft delete. Booleans can't do any of that.

Comment: In that case you could make a user a board member by performing `POST /users/:user_id/roles`. Having a separate controller lets you add additional authorization logic so that you return the correct HTTP code instead and deny an unauthorized user instead of just silently dropping a parameter which is wonky.

Comment: Thanks Max. `@member.reload` was exactly what I needed. I hadn't considered extracting the roles off of the User table, so I'll look into that. Appreciate your help here ; )